# Combining Phrases and Independent Clauses

Tags: grammar, phrases, independent-clauses

Is it grammatically correct to combine an independent clause with a phrase.  For example, "I live in California, specifically in San Francisco."

It sounds correct to my ear but I am unsure if I am "hearing" incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's fine.  In your example, "specifically in San Francisco" is an appositive to "in California".  An appositive adds information without affecting truth.  Here, giving more information about where you live is not relevant to the truth of "I live in California".

Answer (score 1):

Of course!  Many kinds of phrases, appositives, verbal phrases, absolute phrases, can be included with an independent clause.  Combining these different grammatical structures will give your sentences more depth and richness.